# how to clear localStorage in Firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, local-storage

In Firefox, after I perform

`localStorage.clear()`
my localStorage comes back when I refresh the page.

The scenario is:

1) window opens a popup

2) in this popup, I open the dev tools and type in `localStorage.clear();`->local Storage is cleaned !

3)  I refresh the window popup page and..  my localStorage is BACK !

(If I close the popup, then localStroage is cleared)

Everything  works fine in Chrome.

How can I clear localStorage in Firefox ?

I also tried : `localStoparge.removeItem("myItem")` and SAME !

Comment: popup as in a new window on another domain?

Comment: Are you sure the popup page doesn't define a handler that populates local storage? which ff version are you using ?

Comment: 100% right: that was the problem. Trick was FF was slightly acting differntly than chrome