# Clearing localstorage

Tags: javascript, html

What are the ways to clear the `localStorage` from the user-side and from the website-side?

For the website-side I found the "`localStorage.clear()`", but I can't find out if it clears all the localStorage or specifically for the same domain.

As for the user-side, I simply couldn't find any info. about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you think is the difference between user-side and website-side?

Comment: I would say with 100% confidence that `localStorage.clear()` would be domain specific

Comment: Actually it is origin specific, and it is well documented.

Comment: "*A different Storage object is used for the sessionStorage and localStorage for each origin — they function and are controlled separately.*" - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it about `localStorage.clear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`localStorage` is per domain/origin.

Clear it with code using `localStorage.clear()`

Clear it with the browser as you clear cookies/cache.

---

Further reading:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Comment: What do you mean as clearing cookies? there's no cookies... nothing to clear. perhaps you mean by that clearing the cache?

Comment: weird, because chrome and firefox doesn't clear it... the IE does. perhaps something else is involved here, can you tell?

Comment: @qkhckgxhp http://superuser.com/questions/519628/clear-html5-local-storage-on-a-specific-page

Comment: @qkhckgxhp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30508616/how-to-clear-localstorage-in-firefox

Comment: omg! dude, thanks! btw: I think it's a bug or something, because I can't delete this localstorage with clearing the browser data(all of it) with chrome. This method worked! Firefox got same problem, but I don't know how to fix it... too damn weird things(can be coincides with 2 of them buged - hm)

Comment: @qkhckgxhp https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2014/11/05/how-to-clear-out-cookies-flash-cookies-and-local-storage/

Comment: Lol... clearing localstorage with webtools!? :D omfg! but LGSon, you rocks man! thanks for the info!